# How to follow a nav_msgs/path?

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using this [package](https://github.com/open-rdc/fulanghua_navigation) to publish an astroid path.

I would like my robot to be able to follow this published path, I was wondering if anyone have a clue about how to approach this problem?

If I would like to redefine the path to something similar to a sine wave, how would I go about that?

Thank you,
Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295495/how-to-follow-a-nav_msgs/path-?/) by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-27**:
Have you taken a look at the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-27**:
Please don't [crosspost](https://github.com/open-rdc/fulanghua_navigation/issues/73). It wastes time and effort of everyone. Please see our [support page](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Etiquette).

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-27**:
Oh okay, sorry I did not know about that but I understand now.

And yes I have looked at the navigation stack however I am not sure how to integrate move_base with a published path message. I am wondering if anyone have experience with this before and could provide me with some pointers.

Thanks

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-07-20**:
I have the same problem.
Are you finished and solve this problem?
Thanks

**Comment by [gregbowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/155385/gregbowers/) on 2023-06-22**:
Hello

To make your robot follow a published path:

-Publish the desired path using the package you have.
-Subscribe to the published path in your robot's control system.
-Extract the necessary path information from the received message.
-Implement a control algorithm that interprets the path information and generates appropriate commands for the robot.
-Execute the control commands in your robot's hardware or simulation environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, you have three options.

1. Write your own "planner" that follows the path. This can actually be a simple controller without any collision avoidance and should be straightforward.
2. You can write a `GlobalPlannerPlugin` to `move_base` that subscribes to the path you create (or creates it itself) and then passes it down to the local planner. There are quite some questions about this (e.g. [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/39119/custom-global-planner/) or [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/232082/customising-the-path-planning-algorithm/)). Then you have the full capabilities of `move_base` available later on
3. Use `move_base_flex`. This exposes additional actions which should let you do what you want directly. See [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/294278/custom-global-path/) for details.

I personally have done 1 (pretty easy) and 2 (works quite will). EVen though I haven't tested it, I'd say 3 would be the way to go now (though `move_base_flex` is currently still not very stable, but quite actively developed).

---

**EDIT**

About option 1: No, there are no tutorials (that I know of). Just create a subscriber to your path message, and try to follow this using a simple controller. Most basic way would be to implement a simple P[I][D]-controller that trys to stay on the path with a fixed x-velocity (in my experience, PD is totally fine for such a task). If your robot is a differential drive, this is the easiest way.

About option 2: The link to the tutorial is in one of the linked answers above. For [reference](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-28**:
Thank you for your reply, I am interested in the first two options, do you have any tutorials on how to achieve this?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-29**:
see edit above.

**Comment by [hanks](https://answers.ros.org/users/67099/hanks/) on 2021-03-19**:
@mgruhler Hey, I have created a package that computes a global path and I want to execute option 2 from your answer where the global plugin subscribes to this path being published and passes it down to the local planner but am unable to implement it. Here is the code of the plugin I've written to subscribe to the global path and use it but it doesn't work - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kyLQqCFD5ex7VnVXjuRbn9Bn8XsO1fZX?usp=sharing

Please let me know what should I do to solve this.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-03-19**:
no. Post a new question including your code, describe what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far and where you are stuck...

**Comment by [hanks](https://answers.ros.org/users/67099/hanks/) on 2021-03-19**:
@mgruhler Here is my new question - https://answers.ros.org/question/374307/how-to-use-a-subscriber-in-a-global-planner-plugin/